# Amazon SDK : PlatformPrincipal not valid when trying to create a platform

Tags: javascript, amazon-sns

I'm using Amazon SDK for JavaScript and I'd like to create a platform application for iOS.
I'm using the createPlatformApplication(params, function) function, where params is a JavaScript object which should contain a name, a platform (which is equal to 'APNS_SANDBOX' in my case) and an Attribute field containing PlatformCredential and PlatformPrincipal fields.

The problem is that I get the following error :
InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: PlatformPrincipal not valid

I know that, for APNS_SANDBOX platform, the platform principal field must be set with the SSL certificate. Does anyone know if I must copy my SSL certificate into a single string or if I should somehow import the certificate file within my JavaScript code ?

Thanks in advance !
Cheers